# Message Box issues in C#

Tags: c#, messagebox

```
MessageBox.Show ("About Developer"+ "Mandelbrot by Milan." + Environment.NewLine +
            "Email: xyz@abc.com" + Environment.NewLine +
            "Contact No: +977123456789" + Environment.NewLine);
```

I want `About Developer` as title. I searched but I didn't get suitable solution to my problem.

[image]

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms598679(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Replace the + between the first two strings with a comma

Comment: you can also make your own custom message box, it's just a window or form

Comment: @Steve caption is the 2nd parameter; so he needs to switch them after your correction

Comment: @Yollo [y tho?](http://i0.kym-cdn.com/entries/icons/original/000/022/978/yNlQWRM.jpg)

Comment: @john [mhm](https://djordje121.github.io./)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a bunch of overloads on MessageBox.Show. The one you want is the one where you call it with 2 strings like this:

```
MessageBox.Show ("Mandelbrot by Milan." + Environment.NewLine +
                   "Email: xyz@abc.com" + Environment.NewLine +
                   "Contact No: +977123456789" + Environment.NewLine,
                 "About Developer");
```

Comment: It would be worth adding the string concatenation is memory intensive as it creates a bunch of temporary objects.  A better solution would using string.Format